# /usr/local doesn't exist in fresh install Yosemite

Tags: macos, command-line

I am trying to install ssh-copy-id, and it wants to be placed in

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

but when I do

```
cd /usr/local/
```

it responds with

```
-bash: cd: /usr/local/: No such file or directory
```

Is this because I have a fresh install of Yosemite and the changed the location of `/usr/local/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/usr/local does not exist on a standard plain OS X install

You need to create it by

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local
```

In some odd cases e.g. for Homebrew you need to change permissions

Comment: So if I make the folder for `/usr/local/bin/`. Will the items I place in that folder, be immediately available in bash? Or do I have to add a reference to `/usr/local/bin/`?

Comment: Check $PATH - I think that /usr/local/bin is on the standard path - if not you need to add it (I have not had a clean install for many versions :))