# Erased /usr/local/bin directory by mistake

Tags: mac, macos

I am a somewhat newbie to Unix.  I recently started a bash tutorial where I created a hello world bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello World!'
```

then, I moved it into /usr/local/bin using this command:

```
sudo mv hello.sh /usr/local/bin
```

now /bin under /usr/local is no longer a directory, but a file, and when using ls -l on it, I get this output:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Omar:local omarnavarro$ ls
bin
MacBook-Pro-de-Omar:local omarnavarro$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 omarnavarro  staff  32 Apr 11 19:27 bin
MacBook-Pro-de-Omar:local omarnavarro$ cat bin
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello world!'
```

I understand that /usr/local/bin is part of the $PATH, and so I believe there must have been lots of commands in there.  Will this affect me much?  how can I restore the commands that previously lived in /usr/local/bin when it was a directory.  I can't believe I screwed up so badly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [canonical](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac) answer, of course, is to restore /usr/local/bin from your latest backup...

The good news is that if that `mv` command succeeded and created a file called `bin`, then `/usr/local/bin` didn't already exist as a directory on your system, and you've lost nothing. Otherwise, `hello.sh` would have been moved *into* the `/usr/local/bin` directory (which was presumably the intention of the tutorial), it wouldn't have replaced it.

This is not unexpected, as `/usr/local/bin` doesn't generally exist on Macs until you or a 3rd party app creates it. But now you have learned the awesome power of the command line, you know why it's important to keep good backups ;)

Had you mangled `/usr/bin` you'd need to reinstall the system:

- [Deleted /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247739/deleted-usr-local-bin-and-usr-bin-on-os-x)

The good news is system integrity protection (SIP) is making it harder to mangle system files with `sudo`

PS: An easy way to prevent the issue from happening is to always add a trailing `/` if moving files to another directory (or rely on tab completion wich does the same thing): `sudo mv hello.sh /usr/local/bin/`. This way you'll get an error message if the target directory doesn't exist.

Comment: you're awesome.  Thanks for the prompt answer.  I was expecting something to fail somewhere down the line but since all the 'whereis' commands directed me to 'usr/bin', I thought I'd be fine.

Comment: @fd0 Thanks for the clarification. I didn't recall /usr/local being there when I did a clean Sierra install a few months ago, and it [didn't exist on earlier versions of OS X](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157981/2841). But it appears you're right wrt Sierra... will update answer to clarify.