# Batch replace substring with another in filenames

Tags: bash, macos

I have a bunch of files named similar to this:

```
1_1.pngEND1_1.png
```

How would you replace `.pngEND` with `_`?

I've googled this problem and tried  literally 5+ solutions, non of which worked on mac.

Comment: If you edit your post to detail one solution you sel cited to try and the link you used, we might be able to correct what doesn't work for you. (Or point to a better tool to batch rename files). I'd use bash or Python depending on how easy a restore from backup was, but [those tools or just using `mv` could backfire](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280451/erased-usr-local-bin-directory-by-mistake) if you're not already good with the syntax needed..

Comment: I suggest that you look at the venerable `perl rename`- http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename-1.9/bin/rename.PL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are tons of ways to do this, for instance

```
for i in *pngEND*.png; do [[ -e ${i/.pngEND/_} ]] || echo mv "$i" "${i/.pngEND/_}"; done
```

Remove the `echo` if the output looks sensible.

Answer (score 21):

Unless you need a solution you can use in a script, you can do this directly in Finder.

- Select the files you want to rename
- Right click one of them, and choose **Rename N Items...** (where N is the number of selected files)
- Choose the **Replace Text** option in the dropdown
- Enter the text you want to replace (".pngEND") and the text you want to replace it with ("_")
- Click **Rename**

Comment: This is great but is there a way to do this recursively?

Comment: Depends what you mean by recursively. It will happily rename files in multiple different folders in one go, but you will still need to manually find and select them all first before selecting Rename.

Answer (score 2):

If your not familier with terminal or scripts, you can use the mac app called *[NameChanger](https://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/)* (free to use). You can change almost everything in batch on filenames / file extentions.

Comment: For this specific type of batch rename, though, there's no need for 3rd party apps--Finder can do it.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do this, I'd use [rename command](http://brewformulas.org/Rename) available for install via [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/).

Example:

Setup:

`mac:test user$ touch 1_1.pngEND1_1.png`

```
mac:test user$ ls
1_1.pngEND1_1.png
```

Run rename command:

`mac:test user$ rename 's/\.pngEND/_/' *.pngEND*`

Result:

```
mac:test user$ ls
1_1_1_1.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also used the perl `rename` tool to some success.  It also has a dry run option so you can test before you execute the changes.

Comment: Do I need to install anything to use perl commands?

Comment: That just the history.  It's just a tool contained in the package manager that can be used on Linux/GNU-based environments.  It may be in it's own like `perl-rename`.